# How can we visualize osmotic pressure of seawater?

Tags: pressure, osmosis

Wikipedia says [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmotic_pressure) that seawater has an osmotic pressure of 27 atm, which in my opinion is very high. I guess, an application of this in practice is that any reverse osmosis desalination should provide pressure higher than this.

However, I want to make an example of a "normal" direction of osmosis. Wikipedia mentions an arrangement with a U-shaped tube, which has a semipermeable membrane at the bottom. It demonstrates osmotic pressure as difference in the heights of liquids in the two parts of the apparatus. However, the difference in the liquids's height is invariably very small (millimeters). While the pressure of 27 atm corresponds to a difference in height of 270 meters!

Ideally, I would like to see an experiment that pumps water up to a height of 270 m (or at least tens of meters), using osmotic pressure.

Is such a visualization possible in practice? If not, is it because we lack good materials for semi-permeable membranes, or should we use a different setup?

Comment: Not exactly sure what your question is. In particular, what is the meaning of "visualize" here?

Comment: "Visualize" means "demonstrate". I don't know what is unclear about this question; would be happy to improve it but I don't know what to improve.

Comment: I think that it's still unclear. What does "demonstrate" mean? Do you mean (1) rig up a setup in which the osmotic pressure of seawater lifts a column of water to a height of 270 meters? Or do you simply mean (2) rig up an experimental setup which shows that the osmotic pressure of seawater is 27 atmospheres? (1) and (2) are not the same, you know. (2) has almost certainly been done, while (1) almost certainly has not (for the reasons you've already stated).

Comment: I gave the example of reverse osmosis to clarify that I don't want (2). I do want (1); I still hope it's possible in some way.